# Laravel 5.4 how we using fill method?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I use the following method when adding new records to the database;

```
$games=games::create(array('name' => $game_name, 'year' => $game_year, 'type' => $game_type));
```

But in laravel documantation, it says;

If you already have a model instance, you may use the fill method to populate it with an array of attributes:

```
$flight->fill(['name' => 'Flight 22']);
```

How do we know which table in database to add in this case ?

Comment: by default table name is model name plus 's', for example if you have model named Game then it will insert data into games table. here's what the documentation says: "By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the  flights table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a naming convention when it comes to the database. If you have a `Flight` model then Laravel will insert a row on `flights` table.
Also it should be

```
$games = Game::create(array('name' => $game_name, 'year' => $game_year, 'type' => $game_type));
```

since models should be in a singular form and the corresponding table name will be the plural or ends in `s`